# getting error : location: <unknown location>:-1 in "shading" when adding no matter what to the board

Tags: shaders

Thank you all! I was able to fix it with the installation of the version Blender 2.93.0 Alpha (experimental build) and it is working quite well

[image]

The full error in 2.92.0 ... was:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1

bpy.ops.node.select(wait_to_deselect_others=True, mouse_x=779, mouse_y=162, extend=False, deselect_all=True)

bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="CompositorNodeRLayers", use_transform=True)

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\scripts\startup\bl_operators\node.py", line 138, in invoke
    result = self.execute(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\scripts\startup\bl_operators\node.py", line 129, in execute
    self.create_node(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\scripts\startup\bl_operators\node.py", line 92, in create_node
    node = tree.nodes.new(type=node_type)
RuntimeError: Error: Cannot add node of type CompositorNodeRLayers to node tree 'Shader Nodetree'


location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I use blender version 2.92.0 and no addons

added  "vector displacement" and it seams blender respectively shader does not recognice the handles anymore ... so I can not move ore tie the boxes ... but I can still ad others and change the adjustment

[image: unknown location]

I did save
and restart
and repair blender
and reinstall blender
and save as
...

nothing did work so far.

is it a bug, ore just me ?

thanks for the help!

Comment: In what context does error appear? What actions do you perform to get the error? Do you use any addons? What do you intend to add, what type of nodes? What Blender version do you use? You can [edit] your question

Comment: The "unknown location" warning  pops up, but IMO this is not the issue here. The error is re trying to put a compositor node into a shader node tree.  Try adding that node in the `compositor` space.

Comment: well I try to bumpmap a material based on a noise shader ... this seams not posible in the compositor to me ... I redid the prozess again and got the error even earlyer after linking the image to the material

Comment: I just did open a new project and went directly to shading without any action and got the same error again ...

Comment: thank you all for reading and commenting!!! ... I fixed it by myself by instaling the blenderversion 2,93,0 Alpha ... and it is working as expected :) ... so I guess it is just a bug ... I will as well edit my original post to include my fix ...